# How to remove duplicate values from Y-axis in Plotly js

Tags: plotly, plotly.js

Plotly JS has repeating values on X and Y axis.
Issue on Y axis arises when there are constant values in the graph:

[image: Y axis issue image]

To fix x-axis, I tried setting up nticks value but it doesn't work for all the scenarios.

[image: X axis issue image]

Please suggest a work around for the same.

Comment: Please show us the code that you've used to generate these graphs- otherwise your example isn't [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Can you include a link to a codepen perhaps?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.